# Multirow return Query MSACCESS

Tags: sql, multirow

I need to run a query that returns all events that has Electrophysiology Study But don't have  %Ablation%
So in this case I should receive only events 608 and 612. The table has two columns SS_EVENT_EP_ID and STUDYPROCEDURE

Screenshot of tables
https://plus.google.com/photos/105880715521229058253/albums/6026235567691005409/6026235568072337762

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty basic query you are asking. Try reading for the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: SELECT EP_Procedure.SS_Event_EP_ID, EP_Procedure_.StudyProcedure, Event_EP.EventDate
FROM Event_EP INNER JOIN EP_Procedure ON Event_EP.SS_Event_EP_ID = EP_Procedure.SS_Event_EP_ID
WHERE (((EP_Procedure.StudyProcedure)="Electrophysiology study") AND ((Event_EP.EventDate) Between #1/1/2004# And #12/31/2012#));

Comment: I tried like and not like %ablation but that does not work

Comment: Every Event can have few procedures so if i'll run the query i'll receive all rows with Electrophysiology study butrecords where is Electrophysiology study but no %ablation%

Comment: Maybe i need subquery. first i check for the "Electrophysiology study" and then for Not Like %ablation%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw your tables. Yes you are correct, you need a subquery.

What you need is the `EXISTS` operator as well.

```
SELECT EP.SS_Event_EP_ID, EP.StudyProcedure, Event_EP.EventDate 
FROM Event_EP INNER JOIN EP_Procedure As EP
ON Event_EP.SS_Event_EP_ID = EP.SS_Event_EP_ID 
WHERE EP.StudyProcedure = "Electrophysiology study" 
AND (Event_EP.EventDate Between #1/1/2004# And #12/31/2012#)
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    Select SS_Event_EP_ID from EP_Procedure As EP_I
    Where EP_I.SS_Event_EP_ID = EP.SS_Event_EP_ID 
    And EP_I.StudyProcedure Like "%blation%"
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting syntax error "FROM Event_EP INNER JOIN EP_Procedure As EP"

Comment: Are you sure this is in MS Access? If it is in another database, you should ommit the `As`

Comment: MSASSESS 2010   B                                                     SELECT EP_Procedure_BIDMC.SS_Event_EP_ID, EP_Procedure_BIDMC.StudyProcedure, Event_EP.EventDate
FROM Event_EP INNER JOIN EP_Procedure_BIDMC ON Event_EP.SS_Event_EP_ID = EP_Procedure_BIDMC.SS_Event_EP_ID
WHERE (((EP_Procedure_BIDMC.StudyProcedure)="Electrophysiology Study") AND ((Event_EP.EventDate) Between #1/1/2014# And #6/1/2014#));

Comment: If EP_Procedure_BIDMC is the correct name, then just rename it in my query above. `FROM Event_EP INNER JOIN EP_Procedure_BIDMC As EP`